# How to suppress command output safely?

Tags: linux, bash, function, output

Usually on unix systems you can suppress command output by redirecting STDIN and/or STDERR to a file or /dev/null. But what, if you need to pass content to a piped command via STDIN in a bash script?

The example below should make clear what is meant. It's just an example, though - I'm not searching for a solution to this command in specific but to that kind of situation in general. Sadly there are numerous situations where you would want to suppress output in a script, but need to pass content via STDIN, when a command has no switch to submit the information in an other way.

My "problem" is that I wrote a function to execute commands with proper error handling and in which I would like to redirect all output produced by the executed commands to a log file.

Example problem:

```
[18:25:35] [V] root@vbox:~# echo 'test' |read -p 'Test Output' TMP &>/dev/null 
[18:25:36] [V] root@vbox:~# echo $TMP

[18:25:36] [V] root@vbox:~#
```

Any ideas on how to solve my problem?

Comment: `shopt -s lastpipe` or use process substitution i.e. `read -p 'Test Output' TMP &>/dev/null < <(echo 'test')`

Comment: Even `shopt -s lastpipe && echo 'test' |read -p 'Test Output' TMP &>/dev/null` leaves an empty `$TMP`. Happily your command example even works with the `&>/dev/null` in the very end so it is an option for the function.

Comment: note that the `lastpipe` option only works in non-interactive shells. If you test it on your terminal it won't work

Comment: Ah, that explains why it didn't work. Could verify the functionality with a small script - very nice feature! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What user000001 is saying is that all commands in a bash pipeline are executed in subshells. So, when the subshell handling the `read` command exits, the $TMP variable disappears too. You have to account for this and either:

1. avoid subshells (examples given in comment above)
2. do all your work with variables in the same subshell

   ```
   echo test | { read value; echo subshell $value; }; echo parent $value
   ```
3. use a different shell

   ```
   $ ksh -c 'echo test | { read value; echo subshell $value; }; echo parent $value'
   subshell test
   parent test
   ```

Comment: The **process substitution** mentioned by @user000001 did the trick - `read -p 'Test Output' TMP < <(echo 'test') &>/dev/null` works exactly as I want. Learning never stops. :)

Comment: I just realized that this won't help me in certain situations, though, but that's got nothing to do with the answer. I.e. when echoing content to a file through my function, the output is completely redirected to the log. But I realised that putting ` 2>${LOGFULL} #` in the end of `"${2}"` in such cases would work.^^